# How to make a round border SearchView?

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I want to make a `searchview` with rounded bordered for my android application.
So far i made rounded border with white background but search icon and cancel icon disappear and no text showing when type.
i have changed icon color to black and text color to black nothing shows.

how can i achieve that like image here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJTdA.jpg

So far here is my code

searchview_rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
<corners android:radius="30dp"/>
<padding android:left="30dp"
    android:bottom="30dp"
    android:right="30dp"
    android:top="30dp"/>
  </shape>
```

layout

```
    <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:queryHint="Search"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sechview_rounded"
            />
```

Comment: see if it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796955/android-custom-searchview-rounded-corners

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners

Comment: Above code is correct and is working, your problem comes from somewhere else. Maybe your could try to change your theme by adding different items : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897024/7871886

Comment: have you try by changing rounded corner drawable color?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your searchView to below snippet, use `android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"` for hiding underline below the searchView, for detail [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663324/8873091)

```
 <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:queryHint="Search"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/sechview_rounded"
                android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                />
```

Comment: android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent" is above 21 mine is 16 :(

Comment: my minSdkVersion is 16 also and its work, u tried it?